# Indent drawers in plain lists (Org Mode)

Tags: org-mode

I use drawers in Org Mode plain lists, which I insert by hitting `C-c C-x d` after a list entry. With this I get

```
1. [X] This task is completed.
   The task description spans two lines.(here I hit C-c C-x d)
:myDrawer:
(Point is here)
:END:
```

I find it annoying that the drawer is always inserted so that it is aligned with the list item (`1.` in my example above).

How to make it automatically indent itself to the item content? I would like to have

```
1. [X] This task is completed.
   The task description spans two lines.(here I hit C-c C-x d)
   :myDrawer:
   (Point is here)
   :END:
```

Note: I use `org-indent-mode` but it is of no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually indentation happens automatically provided `C-c C-x d` is executed **after** a new line:

```
1. An item.(hit return here)
```

The new cursor position takes indentation into account:

```
1. An item.
   (Cursor ends up here; hit C-c C-x d)
```

One gets:

```
1. An item.
   :myDrawer:
   (Cursor is here)
   :END:
```

So just remember to first hit return before inserting a drawer.